# Multiple loops and value assignment in list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

Suppose I have below data setup:

```
a1=[1,2,3]
a2=['a','b','c']
df1 = DataFrame([['a','x_a'],['b','x_b'],['c','x_c']], columns=['keys','values'])
df1.set_index('keys',inplace=True)
```

This will give me below dataframe:

[image]

I want to create a DataFrame of tuples `(x, y, z)` where `x` is in `a1`, `y` is in `a2`, and `z` is looked up in `df1` by `y`

I can now create (x, y) from below:

```
DataFrame([[(x,y) for x in a1] for y in a2])
```

[image]

My question is how to get `z` also in the tuple by list-comprehension method?

I've tried something like `DataFrame([[(x,y,z) for x in a1] for y in a2 for z:=df1.loc[y]['values']])`, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[(x,y, df1.loc[y, 'values']) for x in a1] for y in a2])
print (df1)
             0            1            2
0  (1, a, x_a)  (2, a, x_a)  (3, a, x_a)
1  (1, b, x_b)  (2, b, x_b)  (3, b, x_b)
2  (1, c, x_c)  (2, c, x_c)  (3, c, x_c)
```

Or select values by dictionary by `dict.get` - better if some no matched values:

```
a1=[1,2,3]
a2=['a','b','c', 'd']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a','x_a'],['b','x_b'],['c','x_c']], columns=['keys','values'])
df1.set_index('keys',inplace=True)

d = df1['values'].to_dict()
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[(x,y, d.get(y, None)) for x in a1] for y in a2])
print (df1)
              0             1             2
0   (1, a, x_a)   (2, a, x_a)   (3, a, x_a)
1   (1, b, x_b)   (2, b, x_b)   (3, b, x_b)
2   (1, c, x_c)   (2, c, x_c)   (3, c, x_c)
3  (1, d, None)  (2, d, None)  (3, d, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the index `keys` in `df1` includes all the values from `a2` (the source of `y`), you can use `df1['values'][y]` to get the appropriate value from `df1`:

```py
a1=[1,2,3]
a2=['a','b','c']
df1 = DataFrame([['a','x_a'],['b','x_b'],['c','x_c']], columns=['keys','values'])
df1.set_index('keys',inplace=True)
pd.DataFrame([[(x,y,df1['values'][y]) for x in a1] for y in a2])
```

Output:

```
             0            1            2
0  (1, a, x_a)  (2, a, x_a)  (3, a, x_a)
1  (1, b, x_b)  (2, b, x_b)  (3, b, x_b)
2  (1, c, x_c)  (2, c, x_c)  (3, c, x_c)
```